# d3js Moving SVG elements inside a transforming group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on a query builder project. I am trying to build a query generator using d3.js. I am stucked in a part where I want to move certain elements inside a transforming group. This is the [repo](https://github.com/Fawzanm/QBuild) and I am stucked in this [function](https://github.com/Fawzanm/QBuild/blob/master/scripts/functions.js). I want to move the operators after connecting it and update the connected lines. Can anyone help me?

```
var circleDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function () {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

    })
    .on('drag', function () {
        var parentQboxGroupId = d3.select(this).select(function () {
            return this.parentNode;
        });
        var grandParent = parentQboxGroupId.select(function(){
            return this.parentNode;
        });

        var drawingGroup = d3.select('#'+grandParent.attr('id'));
        var currentC = d3.select(this);

            dragging = true;
            drawingGroup
            .select('.lineInsideQbox')
            .attr('x1', currentC.attr('cx'))
            .attr('y1', currentC.attr('cy'))
            .style('stroke','green')
            .style('stroke-width','2px');

        dummyLine.src = currentC.attr('id');
        console.log('CIRCLE IS BEING DRAGGED' + JSON.stringify(dummyLine));


    })
    .on('dragend', function () {
        console.log('drag circle end');

        //if(!selectedCircle.id){
        //    dummyLine.target = selectedQbox.id;
        //}
        dummyLine.target = selectedCircle.id;
        dragging = false;

        console.log('DRAG END : SELCTED NODE : '+ JSON.stringify(selectedCircle));
        console.log('DRAG END : DUMMY LINE : '+ JSON.stringify(dummyLine));

        var targetNode = d3.select('#'+dummyLine.target);
        var srcNode = d3.select('#'+dummyLine.src);
        console.log('split : ' + dummyLine.src.split('--'));

        var group = '#' + (dummyLine.src).split('--')[1];
        console.log('G: ' + group);
        d3.select(group).append('line')
            .attr('id', function () {


                var a = (dummyLine.src).split('--');
                var b = (dummyLine.target).split('--');
                if( a[0]== 'nodeRight'){
                    return dummyLine.src + '__' + dummyLine.target;
                }else{
                    return dummyLine.target + '__' + dummyLine.src;
                }

            })
            .attr('class', function () {
                var a = (dummyLine.src).split('--');
                var b = (dummyLine.target).split('--');
                return 'line '+ a[1]+' '+b[1];
            })
            .attr('x1', srcNode.attr('cx'))
            .attr('y1',srcNode.attr('cy'))
            .attr('x2',targetNode.attr('cx'))
            .attr('y2',targetNode.attr('cy'))
            .style('stroke', 'black')
            .style('stroke-width', '3px')
        ;
        dummyLine.src = null;
        dummyLine.target = null;
    });
```

EDIT : When I try to drop a query Box. I can drop other operators inside it. Then I should be able to connect them inside. Here is the image showing what I am trying.

[image]

After the connections made, I try yo move large box & small operators individually. That's where the code break.

Comment: At which part of code it is breaking? What is the error being shown?

Comment: edit is made. please check it.

Comment: How do you set the value for `selectedCircle` variable? I could not find any assignment statement for that variable.

Comment: selectedCircle is set when I hover over a circle. https://github.com/Fawzanm/QBuild/blob/master/scripts/operatorDrag.js Line 131. selectedSircle is defined on scripts/layout.js

Comment: I cant access your image, could you embed it in the question?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ELc4Xbp.png  yes. Here it is

Comment: @Gilsha any luck? :/

Comment: Sorry Fawzan. I am a little busy in my work. Can you add a jsfiddle? I shall look into this a little later.

Comment: It has so many components, I will try to put everything into one place.

Comment: @Gilsha it's quite tedeous to add images and all to fiddle, so I have uploaded it to a host. you can take a look at it here. http://js.mutexlk.com

Comment: Hi fawzan, did you try my approach below?

Comment: Thanks @StaceyBurns I will update you as soon as tried that method.

Comment: @StaceyBurns I have checked your code. It works fine. but it still giving me  a headache. please check the comment. :/

Comment: @Fawzan, I had a look at it and I think you should be able to work out how to get it working for two outer operators connected together. If you understand the concept of updating the circle and line positions below, you should be able to use this same logic to make it work . I'm not going to post another update to the code as I think by this point you have enough to go on to be able to do it yourself.

Comment: @stacy i completely understand your answer. My question is, let is say i use the same technique and transform the image for query box and change the location for the circles. What happens to the operators and lines inside? Should i move them individually as well?

Comment: Only just noticing this comment. I think you need to check all objects that are connected to the object being dragged and update the values to keep everything in synch for the next possible move. I think the only difference between the code below and what you need is, instead of checking all the lines within the parent group, you actually need to check all the lines within the total view box.

Comment: @StaceyBurns I am trying a little different approach, But I am quite stuck with the teansformation. do you think you can help meout here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085240/d3js-transforming-nested-group-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that to move the operator, you use a translate to move the whole group ( tag) which includes the image, the two circles and the line. You then set the other end of the line using CX, CY values of the other operator it is connected to. 
This wont work because the CX and CY values of the circles are not updated when you perform a translate, so on a second move, it would put the x, y values at the original point of the circles, not to the moved point. 
To resolve, instead of translating the whole group, translate only the image, update the cx and cy values of the circles and then update the line x, y values with the new cx, cy of the circles:

All of the amendments needed are within your operatorDrag.js file. 
First of all, when you append the circles, add an attribute which holds the original cx and cy values. We will need these when calculating the new cx, cy when dragging the operator:

change from this:

```
 var op = currGroup
            .append('image')
            .attr('class', 'operator')
            .attr('width', elem.attr('width') * 0.75)
            .attr('height', elem.attr('height') * 0.75)
            .attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0])
            .attr('y', d3.mouse(this)[1])
            .attr('xlink:href', elem.attr('href'));

        currGroup
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node nodeLeft')
            .attr('id', function () {
                return 'nodeLeft--' + currGroup.attr('id');
            })
            .attr('cx', op.attr('x'))
            .attr('cy', op.attr('height') / 2 + Number(op.attr('y')))
            .attr('r', 5)
            .style('fill', 'red')
            .on('mouseover', function () {
                selectedCircle = {
                    id: d3.select(this).attr('id'),
                    cls: 'nodeLeft'
                }
            })
            .call(circleDrag)
        ;

        currGroup
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node nodeRight')
            .attr('id', function () {
                return 'nodeRight--' + currGroup.attr('id');
            })
            .attr('cx', Number(op.attr('x')) + Number(op.attr('width')))
            .attr('cy', op.attr('height') / 2 + Number(op.attr('y')))
            .attr('r', 5)
            .style('fill', 'red')

            .on('mouseover', function () {
                selectedCircle = {
                    id: d3.select(this).attr('id'),
                    cls: 'nodeRight'
                }
            })
            .call(circleDrag)

        ;
```

To this (the updated code is contained in comments starting with #SB):

```
     var op = currGroup
                    .append('image')
                    .attr('class', 'operator')
                    .attr('width', elem.attr('width') * 0.75)
                    .attr('height', elem.attr('height') * 0.75)
                    .attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0])
                    .attr('y', d3.mouse(this)[1])
                    .attr('xlink:href', elem.attr('href'));

                currGroup
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'node nodeLeft')
                    .attr('id', function () {
                        return 'nodeLeft--' + currGroup.attr('id');
                    })
                    .attr('cx', op.attr('x'))
                    .attr('cy', op.attr('height') / 2 + Number(op.attr('y')))

                // #SB: add a reference to the original cx and cy position.
                // we will need it to set new cx cy when moving operator

                    .attr('data-cx', op.attr('x'))
                    .attr('data-cy', op.attr('height') / 2 + Number(op.attr('y')))
               //----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    .attr('r', 5)
                    .style('fill', 'red')
                    .on('mouseover', function () {
                        selectedCircle = {
                            id: d3.select(this).attr('id'),
                            cls: 'nodeLeft'
                        }
                    })
                    .call(circleDrag)
                ;

                currGroup
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'node nodeRight')
                    .attr('id', function () {
                        return 'nodeRight--' + currGroup.attr('id');
                    })
                    .attr('cx', Number(op.attr('x')) + Number(op.attr('width')))
                    .attr('cy', op.attr('height') / 2 + Number(op.attr('y')))
                // #SB: add a reference to the original cx and cy position.
                // we will need it to set new cx cy when moving operator

                    .attr('data-cx', Number(op.attr('x')) + Number(op.attr('width')))
                    .attr('data-cy', op.attr('height') / 2 + Number(op.attr('y')))
               //----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    .attr('r', 5)
                    .style('fill', 'red')

                    .on('mouseover', function () {
                        selectedCircle = {
                            id: d3.select(this).attr('id'),
                            cls: 'nodeRight'
                        }
                    })
                    .call(circleDrag)

                ;
```

Once you have done this, go to your on drag method for the operators. This is the code we are going to change:

```
               .on('drag', function () {

                    var g = d3.select(this);

                    var currentOp = g.select('.operator');
                    var parent = g.select(function () {
                        return this.parentNode;
                    }).select('.qbox');


                    var dx = d3.event.x;
                    var dy = d3.event.y;

                    var mouse = {dx: d3.event.x, dy: d3.event.y};
                    var currentObj = {
                        x: currentOp.attr('x'),
                        y: currentOp.attr('y'),
                        width: currentOp.attr('width'),
                        height: currentOp.attr('height')
                    };
                    var parentObj = {
                        x: parent.attr('x'),
                        y: parent.attr('y'),
                        width: parent.attr('width'),
                        height: parent.attr('height')
                    };


                    //console.log('parent width : ' + parent.attr('width'));
                    //console.log('parent width : ' + currentOp.attr('width'));
                    //g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')');
                    var loc = getXY(mouse, currentObj, parentObj);
                    g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + loc.x + ',' + loc.y + ')');


                    d3.select('#' + g.attr('id')).selectAll('.line')[0].forEach(function (e1) {

                        var line = d3.select(e1);
                        console.log('-------------------');
                        console.log('line : ' + line.attr('id'));
                        console.log('-------------------');
                        var split = line.attr('id').split('__');
                        if(g.attr('id') == split[0]){
                            //change x2, y2
                            var otherNode = d3.select('#'+split[1]);
                            line.attr('x2', otherNode.attr('cx'));
                            line.attr('y2', otherNode.attr('cy'));
                        }else{
                            var otherNode = d3.select('#'+split[0]);
                            line.attr('x1', otherNode.attr('cx'));
                            line.attr('y1', otherNode.attr('cy'));
                        }


                    })


                }))
```

First thing is, do not translate the whole object, only the image:

```
              var g = d3.select(this);

                    var currentOp = g.select('.operator');

                    var parent = g.select(function () {
                        return this.parentNode;
                    }).select('.qbox');

                    //#SB: added a reference to the parent id
                    var parent_id = g.select(function () {
                        return this.parentNode;
                    }).attr('id');

                    //---------------------------------------

                    var dx = d3.event.x;
                    var dy = d3.event.y;

                    var mouse = {dx: d3.event.x, dy: d3.event.y};
                    var currentObj = {
                        x: currentOp.attr('x'),
                        y: currentOp.attr('y'),
                        width: currentOp.attr('width'),
                        height: currentOp.attr('height')
                    };
                    var parentObj = {
                        x: parent.attr('x'),
                        y: parent.attr('y'),
                        width: parent.attr('width'),
                        height: parent.attr('height')
                    };



                    var loc = getXY(mouse, currentObj, parentObj);


                    //#SB: Do not translate everything, the cx, cy values of the circle are not updated
                    // when translating which will make future moves calculate incorrectly
                    g.selectAll('image').attr('transform', 'translate(' + loc.x + ',' + loc.y + ')');
```

Then, instead of translating the circles, change their cx, and cy values using the original cx, cy and translate values:

```
                   g.selectAll('circle')
                    .attr('cx', function () {

                        return parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('data-cx')) + parseFloat(loc.x);
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function () {

                        return parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('data-cy')) + parseFloat(loc.y);
                    });
```

The last thing is the update to the lines. In your original code, you were selecting all lines within the operator group but you will actually miss some lines by only selecting this group. Some lines can be a part of another operator group but be connected to the operator that is moving. 
In this case we should select all lines within the parent group and check if the line is connected to the operator we are moving. 
If it is connected then we update the x and y values:

```
//#SB: Select all the lines in the parent group instead of only group of the
                        // operator we are moving. There can be lines that exists on other groups that 
                        // do not exist within the group that is being moved. 


                        d3.select('#' + parent_id).selectAll('.line')[0].forEach(function (el) {

var parent_id = g.attr('id')
                            var line = d3.select(el)
                            var nodeType = line.attr('id').split("__");  // id tells us if the line is connected to the left or right node
                            var operators = line.attr('class').split(" ");  // class holds info on what operators the line is connected to
                            var sourceCircleId = nodeType[0].split("--")[0] + '--' + operators[1];
                            var targetCircleId = nodeType[1].split("--")[0] + '--' + operators[2]; 

                           if (parent_id == operators[1] || parent_id == operators[2]) {  // the line is connected to the operator we are moving 

                                line.attr('x1', d3.select('#' + sourceCircleId).attr('cx'))
                                line.attr('y1', d3.select('#' + sourceCircleId).attr('cy'))
                                line.attr('x2', d3.select('#' + targetCircleId).attr('cx'))
                                line.attr('y2', d3.select('#' + targetCircleId).attr('cy'))

                            }

                        });
```

Complete OnDrag code:

```
             .on('drag', function () {

                    var g = d3.select(this);

                    var currentOp = g.select('.operator');

                    var parent = g.select(function () {
                        return this.parentNode;
                    }).select('.qbox');

                    //#SB: added a reference to the parent id
                    var parent_id = g.select(function () {
                        return this.parentNode;
                    }).attr('id');

                    //---------------------------------------

                    var dx = d3.event.x;
                    var dy = d3.event.y;

                    var mouse = {dx: d3.event.x, dy: d3.event.y};
                    var currentObj = {
                        x: currentOp.attr('x'),
                        y: currentOp.attr('y'),
                        width: currentOp.attr('width'),
                        height: currentOp.attr('height')
                    };
                    var parentObj = {
                        x: parent.attr('x'),
                        y: parent.attr('y'),
                        width: parent.attr('width'),
                        height: parent.attr('height')
                    };



                    var loc = getXY(mouse, currentObj, parentObj);


                    //#SB: Do not translate everything, the cx, cy values of the circle are not updated
                    // when translating which will make future moves calculate incorrectly
                    g.selectAll('image').attr('transform', 'translate(' + loc.x + ',' + loc.y + ')');

                    g.selectAll('circle')
                    .attr('cx', function () {

                        return parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('data-cx')) + parseFloat(loc.x);
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function () {

                        return parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('data-cy')) + parseFloat(loc.y);
                    });


                    //#SB: Select all the lines in the parent group instead of only group of the
                    // operator we are moving. There can be lines that exists on other groups that 
                    // do not exist within the group that is being moved. 


                    d3.select('#' + parent_id).selectAll('.line')[0].forEach(function (el) {

 var parent_id = g.attr('id')
                            var line = d3.select(el)
                            var nodeType = line.attr('id').split("__");  // id tells us if the line is connected to the left or right node
                            var operators = line.attr('class').split(" ");  // class holds info on what operators the line is connected to
                            var sourceCircleId = nodeType[0].split("--")[0] + '--' + operators[1];
                            var targetCircleId = nodeType[1].split("--")[0] + '--' + operators[2];  

                       if (parent_id == operators[1] || parent_id == operators[2]) {  // the line is connected to the operator we are moving 

                            line.attr('x1', d3.select('#' + sourceCircleId).attr('cx'))
                            line.attr('y1', d3.select('#' + sourceCircleId).attr('cy'))
                            line.attr('x2', d3.select('#' + targetCircleId).attr('cx'))
                            line.attr('y2', d3.select('#' + targetCircleId).attr('cy'))

                        }

                    });



                }))
```

Comment: @Stacy your code completely works fine for the operators inside a box, But when I try to connect the boxes (after dragging it) I cannot drag the lines to connect boxes. It starts from somewhere and ends in somewhere.

Comment: The problem is, After adding the operators inside the box, When I try to add the box. I again translate the entire group. so the same problem occurs as previous. What do you think I should do? Move all the elements individually?

Comment: Let me have a look at the code. I didn't test this but I presumed the id and class set up would have been the same for connecting to outside boxes. If not it probably just needs a little tweak somewhere.

Comment: I tried some tweaks, but I couldn't figure it out. Would be a great help if you can lend a hand.

Comment: BTW I have update the repo & js.mutexlk.com sources. you can take a look.