# d3js transforming nested group images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on [this][1] d3 project. Basically I am trying to create a SQL like query builder. I can drop boxes to the drawing area & other operators inside the box. Then I should be able to connect them all. I am trying to translate 2 images which are nested in groups. I want to move the small items inside the big box. I can transform the big box and small operators separately. Problem happens When I try to move the small operators first. I want to move the small operators, then big boxes. meanwhile I want to keep the relative position of small operators and big box same. But when I try to move the large box after moving one of the small box it resets its location. Here is a demo of my work in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fawzan/coacf0xp/)

```
<g id="draw">

    <rect class="container" height="400" width="400" x="0" y="0" style="fill:gray"></rect>

    <g class="qbox" id="qbox">

        <line id="dummyLine" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" visibility="hidden"
              style='stroke:red; stroke-width:4px'></line>

        <image x="10" y="10" class="container" initial-x="10" initial-y="10" xlink:href="http://i60.tinypic.com/20ic9e.png"
               width="110"
               height="110"></image>
        <circle class="left" id="qbox-left" initial-cx="10" initial-cy="65" cx="10" cy="65" r="5"
                style="fill:red"></circle>
        <circle class="right" id="qbox-right" initial-cx="120" initial-cy="65" cx="120" cy="65" r="5"
                style="fill:red"></circle>

        <g id="op1" class="op">
            <image class="opim" x="10" y="10" class="container" initial-x="10" initial-y="10"
                   xlink:href="http://i58.tinypic.com/imlzs9.png" width="50"
                   height="50"></image>
            <circle id="op1-left" class="left" initial-cx="10" initial-cy="35" cx="10" cy="35" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
            <circle id="op1-right" class="right" initial-cx="60" initial-cy="35" cx="60" cy="35" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
        </g>

        <g id="op2" class="op">
            <image class="opim" x="60" y="60" initial-x="60" initial-y="60"
                   xlink:href="http://i58.tinypic.com/imlzs9.png" width="50"
                   height="50"></image>
            <circle id="op2-left" class="left" initial-cx="60" initial-cy="85" cx="60" cy="85" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
            <circle id="op2-right" class="right" initial-cx="110" initial-cy="85" cx="110" cy="85" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
        </g>

    </g>

    <g class="qbox" id="qbox2" >

        <line id="dummyLine" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" visibility="hidden"
              style='stroke:red; stroke-width:4px'></line>

        <image x="110" y="110" class="container" initial-x="110" initial-y="110" xlink:href="http://i60.tinypic.com/20ic9e.png"
               width="110"
               height="110"></image>
        <circle class="left" id="qbox-left" initial-cx="110" initial-cy="165" cx="110" cy="165" r="5"
                style="fill:red"></circle>
        <circle class="right" id="qbox-right" initial-cx="220" initial-cy="265" cx="220" cy="165" r="5"
                style="fill:red"></circle>

        <g id="op3" class="op">
            <image class="opim" x="110" y="110" class="container" initial-x="110" initial-y="110"
                   xlink:href="http://i58.tinypic.com/imlzs9.png" width="50"
                   height="50"></image>
            <circle id="op1-left" class="left" initial-cx="110" initial-cy="135" cx="110" cy="135" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
            <circle id="op1-right" class="right" initial-cx="160" initial-cy="135" cx="160" cy="135" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="op4" class="op">
            <image class="opim" x="160" y="160" initial-x="160" initial-y="160"
                   xlink:href="http://i58.tinypic.com/imlzs9.png" width="50"
                   height="50"></image>
            <circle id="op2-left" class="left" initial-cx="160" initial-cy="185" cx="160" cy="185" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
            <circle id="op2-right" class="right" initial-cx="210" initial-cy="185" cx="210" cy="185" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
        </g>



    </g>


</g>
```

```
    var qBox = d3.selectAll('.qbox')
            .on('dblclick', function () {
                var g = d3.select(this);
                var scale = 'scale(1.2,1.2)';
                g.attr('transform', g.attr('transform') + ' ' + scale);
            });
    var opBox = d3.selectAll('.op');
    var circles = d3.selectAll('circle');


    var cDrag = d3.behavior.drag()

                    .on('dragstart', function () {
                        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    })
                    .on('drag', function () {

                        var dummyLine = d3.select('#dummyLine');
                        var me = d3.select(this);

                        var transForm = me.node().getCTM();
                        var t2 = me.select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        }).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        }).select('circle').node().getCTM();

                        var tC = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr('transform')).translate;
                        var tP = d3.transform(d3.select(this).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        }).attr('transform')).translate;

                        console.log(transForm);

                        var meX = t2['e'];
                        var meY = t2['f'];


                        dummyLine
                                .style('visibility', 'visible')
                                .attr('tx1', Number(me.attr('cx')))
                                .attr('x1', Number(me.attr('cx')) + (Number(transForm['e'] - Number(meX))))
                                .attr('ty1', Number(me.attr('cy')))
                                .attr('y1', Number(me.attr('cy')) + (Number(transForm['f'] - Number(meY))))
                                .attr('x2', Number(d3.event.x) )
                                .attr('tx2', Number(d3.event.x) + Number(tP[0]) - Number(tC[0]))
                                .attr('y2', Number(d3.event.y) )
                                .attr('ty2', Number(d3.event.y) + Number(tP[1]) - Number(tC[0]))
                                .attr('start', me.attr('id'))

                        ;

                    })
                    .on('dragend', function () {

                        var g = d3.select(this).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        }).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        });


                        var dummyLine = d3.select('#dummyLine');

                        dummyLine.style('visibility', 'hidden');

                        d3.select('.qbox')
                                .append('line')
                                .attr('id', function () {
                                    return dummyLine.attr('start') + '__' + circleID;
                                })

                                .attr('x1', dummyLine.attr('x1'))
                                .attr('ix1', dummyLine.attr('tx1'))
                                .attr('x2', dummyLine.attr('x2'))
                                .attr('ix2', d3.select('#' + circleID).attr('cx'))
                                .attr('y1', dummyLine.attr('y1'))
                                .attr('iy1', dummyLine.attr('ty1'))
                                .attr('y2', dummyLine.attr('y2'))
                                .attr('iy2', d3.select('#' + circleID).attr('cy'))
                                .attr('start', dummyLine.attr('start'))
                                .attr('end', circleID)
                                .style('stroke', 'green')
                                .style('stroke-width', '2px')

                        ;
                    })
            ;

    var svg = d3.select('svg').node();

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function () {
                        var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
                        return {x: t[0], y: t[1]};
                    }).on('dragstart', function () {
                        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    }).on('drag', function () {

                        var g = d3.select(this);

                        var mouse = {dx: d3.event.x, dy: d3.event.y};
                        var currentObj = {
                            x: g.select('image').attr('x'),
                            y: g.select('image').attr('y'),
                            width: g.select('image').attr('width'),
                            height: g.select('image').attr('height')
                        };
                        var parentObj = {
                            x: (Number(g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('x'))), // + Number(d3.transform(parent.attr('transform')).translate[0])),
                            y: (Number(g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('y'))), // + Number(d3.transform(parent.attr('transform')).translate[1])),
                            width: g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('width'),
                            height: g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('height')
                        };


                        var loc = getXY(mouse, currentObj, parentObj);
                        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + loc.x + ',' + loc.y + ')');
//                        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');

                        var groupId = d3.select(this).attr('id');
                        var groupClass = d3.select(this).attr('class');

                        d3.selectAll('line')[0].forEach(function (e1) {

                            var line = d3.select(e1);
//                            console.log('groupId: ', groupId);


                            if (line.attr('id') != 'dummyLine' && groupClass != 'qbox') {

//                                console.log('--------------');
//                                console.log('lineId: ', line.attr('id'));

                                var lineStart = line.attr('start').split('-')[0];
                                var lineEnd = line.attr('end').split('-')[0];
//                                console.log('lineStatr : ', lineStart);
//                                console.log('lineEnd : ', lineEnd);

                                var t = d3.transform(d3.select('#' + groupId).attr('transform')).translate;
                                var t2 = d3.transform(d3.select('#' + groupId).select(function () {
                                    return this.parentNode;
                                }).attr('transform')).translate;

                                console.log('groupID ', groupId);

                                if (lineStart == groupId) {
                                    var t = d3.transform(d3.select('#' + lineStart).attr('transform')).translate;

                                    line.attr('x1', Number(line.attr('ix1')) + (Number(t[0])));
                                    line.attr('y1', Number(line.attr('iy1')) + Number(t[1]));
//                                    line.attr('x1', Number(line.attr('ix1')) - (-Number(t[0])+Number(t2[0])));
//                                    line.attr('y1', Number(line.attr('iy1')) - (-Number(t[1]+Number(t2[1]))));

                                }

                                if (lineEnd == groupId) {
                                    var t = d3.transform(d3.select('#' + lineEnd).attr('transform')).translate;

                                    line.attr('x2', Number(line.attr('ix2')) + Number(t[0]));
                                    line.attr('y2', Number(line.attr('iy2')) + Number(t[1]));
//                                    line.attr('x2', Number(line.attr('ix2')) - Number(t[0]));
//                                    line.attr('y2', Number(line.attr('iy2')) - Number(t[1]));
//                                    line.attr('x2', Number(line.attr('ix2')) - (Number(t[0]+Number(t2[0]))));
//                                    line.attr('y2', Number(line.attr('iy2')) - (Number(t[1]+Number(t2[1]))));

                                }

                            }


                        });


                    })

            ;

    opBox.call(drag);
    qBox.call(drag);
    circles.call(cDrag);

    var circleID;

    circles.on('mouseover', function () {
        circleID = d3.select(this).attr('id');
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        circleID = null;
    })
```

**PS : I connect two elements by dragging the circles and dropping into another circle.**

Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: If you want the small operators to stay where they are, you shouldn't be translating them on the large operators drag.

Comment: Just to add to the comment as I think its a bit more complicated than I first imagined. I think that if the operator is outside the large operator, it should stay in the position it is in right? Only when it is inside the large operator it should drag with its parent. So I think you need a data attribute to act as a flag to tell you if the operator is inside our outside a container. If its inside you should move it with the parent and if its outside you should keep it where it is. Does that make sense?

Comment: @StaceyBurns yes, you are correct. that is what I want to achieve. may be  if you can try my fiddle you would see if I stop transforming the small operators when I transform the large operator, it stays where it is. It doesn't move at all. I have to somehow translate it. Because when I want to drag the big box I translate the image not the group.

Comment: I think you're making this way more complicated than it needs to be https://jsfiddle.net/g1vbm66x/1/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have already tried that, Problem comes from another aspect, I have another SO question related to this. I want to update the circles as well. Because I want to connect the circles with lines & update the lines when I drag the operators. Thats why I am translating the image and updating the circles without translating the group. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935084/d3js-moving-svg-elements-inside-a-transforming-group

Comment: You should edit this question then to tell us what you really want to do.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have made the edit with my problem. Could you be able to help? I have tried so many things. I am willing to double the bounty for the person who solves this.

Comment: It would help if you could narrow it down to a minimal example.

Comment: Thats what i had in the previous post before edit. Quite difficult to narrow the problem, have you tried the demo? Can you point out what happens when I try to drop a box, drag it, drop some operator inside it? It would be enough for me.

Comment: @Fawzan, I think you need to take a step back and think about your overall design. 
You have one requirement (from your first question) that had a parent box where child boxes are nested inside a group. 
This question now shows there is no parent child relationship any more, they are both their own groups. 
You have child operators that can be added inside a parent operator but you also require that the child can be moved outside, independent of the parent. 
Its unclear to me what your end goal is and think your question needs to explain your requirements in more detail.

Comment: @StaceyBurns If you take a close look, it is the same problem.  Big Square here refers to the PARENT and small operators refers to the CHILD. I want the same thing. like you said I would like to take a step back, before that can anyone suggest me what the actual problem is? or any new approaches?

Comment: @Fawzan I went through your code.
My observations:
You have a group with id=query_box_X class=query_box and all its child with in it....this is fine
So when you drag you apply transformation to the image class=qbox for the circle class="node" you manage the cx and cy.
As per me If I were you I would have done the transform on its parent group class="query_box" this will relieve me of managing the cx and cy child circles. Now when i will translate the main group on dragging the circle and the image will all move along with it.

Comment: @Cyril I tried that approch, I cannot use it because I want to update the connected lines. to do that, I need the cx, cy values. That's why I update the circles seperately.

Comment: Now why does it jump?
If you check your code when you drag for the FIRST time into your draw area then you manage its position with x and y of the image and all its circle siblings.
Now after the first drag you manage the drag effect by transform only on the image tag. thus when the second element gets dropped as a child it does not know about the translate you have applied on image and thus it appears to fall apart.

Comment: @Fawzan is it possible for you to have a chat with me I think SO has some mechanism to chat...

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to do chat. Let me see.

Comment: @Cyril Looks like chat is not working on SO. is it possible to chat on G+ ?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I brough it to a smaller model, can you help now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all sort of troubles, I found my answer. Actually it is all about the coordinate system and where to put stuff and how to organize it. Once I fugured that out, Answer is pretty obvious.

```
<svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: blue">


    <g id="draw">

        <rect class="container" height="500" width="500" x="0" y="0" style="fill:yellow"></rect>

        <line class="dummyLineOutsideQbox"></line>

        <g class="qbox" id="qbox">

            <line class="dummyLineInsideQbox"></line>


            <image x="10" y="10" class="container" initial-x="10" initial-y="10" xlink:href="images/query.png"
                   width="110"
                   height="110"></image>
            <circle class="left" id="qbox-left" initial-cx="10" initial-cy="65" cx="10" cy="65" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
            <circle class="right" id="qbox-right" initial-cx="120" initial-cy="65" cx="120" cy="65" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>

            <g id="op1" class="op">
                <image class="opim" x="10" y="10" class="container" initial-x="10" initial-y="10"
                       xlink:href="images/filter.png" width="50"
                       height="50"></image>
                <circle id="op1-left" class="left" initial-cx="10" initial-cy="35" cx="10" cy="35" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
                <circle id="op1-right" class="right" initial-cx="60" initial-cy="35" cx="60" cy="35" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
            </g>

            <g id="op2" class="op">
                <image class="opim" x="60" y="60" initial-x="60" initial-y="60"
                       xlink:href="images/filter.png" width="50"
                       height="50"></image>
                <circle id="op2-left" class="left" initial-cx="60" initial-cy="85" cx="60" cy="85" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
                <circle id="op2-right" class="right" initial-cx="110" initial-cy="85" cx="110" cy="85" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
            </g>

        </g>

        <g class="qbox" id="qbox2">

            <line class="dummyLineInsideQbox"></line>

            <image x="110" y="110" class="container" initial-x="110" initial-y="110" xlink:href="images/query.png"
                   width="110"
                   height="110"></image>
            <circle class="left" id="qbox2-left" initial-cx="110" initial-cy="165" cx="110" cy="165" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>
            <circle class="right" id="qbox2-right" initial-cx="220" initial-cy="265" cx="220" cy="165" r="5"
                    style="fill:red"></circle>

            <g id="op3" class="op">
                <image class="opim" x="110" y="110" class="container" initial-x="110" initial-y="110"
                       xlink:href="images/filter.png" width="50"
                       height="50"></image>
                <circle id="op3-left" class="left" initial-cx="110" initial-cy="135" cx="110" cy="135" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
                <circle id="op3-right" class="right" initial-cx="160" initial-cy="135" cx="160" cy="135" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
            </g>
            <g id="op4" class="op">
                <image class="opim" x="160" y="160" initial-x="160" initial-y="160"
                       xlink:href="images/filter.png" width="50"
                       height="50"></image>
                <circle id="op4-left" class="left" initial-cx="160" initial-cy="185" cx="160" cy="185" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
                <circle id="op4-right" class="right" initial-cx="210" initial-cy="185" cx="210" cy="185" r="5"
                        style="fill:red"></circle>
            </g>


        </g>


    </g>

</svg>

<script>
    var qBox = d3.selectAll('.qbox')
            .on('dblclick', function () {
                var g = d3.select(this);
                var scale = 'scale(1.2,1.2)';
                g.attr('transform', g.attr('transform') + ' ' + scale);
            });
    var opBox = d3.selectAll('.op');
    var circles = d3.selectAll('circle');


    var cDrag = d3.behavior.drag()

                    .on('dragstart', function () {
                        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    })
                    .on('drag', function () {

                        var thisCircle = d3.select(this);
                        var thisGroup = thisCircle.select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        });
                        var thisGroupTransform = d3.transform(thisGroup.attr('transform')).translate;

                        var thisGroupParent = d3.select(this).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        }).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        });

                        var thisGroupParentId = thisGroupParent.attr('id');
                        var thisGroupParentClass = thisGroupParent.attr('class');


                        if (thisGroupParentClass == 'qbox') {
                            dummyLine = d3.select('#' + thisGroupParentId).select('.dummyLineInsideQbox');
                        }
                        else {
                            dummyLine = d3.select('#' + thisGroupParentId).select('.dummyLineOutsideQbox');

                        }

                        console.log('dummyLine ', dummyLine.attr('class'));


                        dummyLine
                                .style('visibility', 'visible')
                                .style('stroke', 'red')
                                .style('stroke-width', '3px')
                                .attr('x1', Number(thisCircle.attr('cx')) + thisGroupTransform[0])
                                .attr('real-x1', thisCircle.attr('cx'))
                                .attr('y1', Number(thisCircle.attr('cy')) + thisGroupTransform[1])
                                .attr('real-y1', thisCircle.attr('cy'))
                                .attr('x2', d3.mouse(this)[0] + thisGroupTransform[0])
                                .attr('y2', d3.mouse(this)[1] + thisGroupTransform[1])
                                .attr('startGroup', thisGroup.attr('id'))
                                .attr('startCircleClass', thisCircle.attr('class'))
                        ;


                    })
                    .on('dragend', function () {


                        var thisCircle = d3.select('#' + circleID);
                        var thisCircleClass = thisCircle.attr('class');
                        var thisGroup = thisCircle.select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        });

                        var thisGroupTransform = d3.transform(thisGroup.attr('transform')).translate;

                        var thisGroupParent = d3.select(this).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        }).select(function () {
                            return this.parentNode;
                        });

                        var thisGroupParentId = thisGroupParent.attr('id');
                        var thisGroupParentClass = thisGroupParent.attr('class');


                        var sourceCircleClass = dummyLine.attr('startCircleClass');
                        var sourceGroup = d3.select('#' + dummyLine.attr('startGroup'));

                        console.log('SOURCE GROUP :', sourceGroup.attr('id'));

                        var targetLineGroup;
                        var lineClass;

                        var t = [0, 0];
                        var x1, x2, y1, y2;

                        if (( sourceGroup.attr('class') == 'op') || (thisGroup.attr('class') == 'op')) {

                            if (sourceGroup.attr('class') == 'op') {
                                targetLineGroup = sourceGroup.select(function () {
                                    return this.parentNode;
                                });
//                                console.log('I am on line 185');
                            } else {
                                targetLineGroup = thisGroup.select(function () {
                                    return this.parentNode;
                                });
//                                console.log('I am on line 190');

                            }
                            lineClass = 'in';
                            x1 = startCircle.attr('cx');
                            y1 = startCircle.attr('cy');
                            x2 = thisCircle.attr('cx');
                            y2 = thisCircle.attr('cy');

                        }

                        if ((sourceGroup.attr('class') == 'qbox') && (thisGroup.attr('class') == 'qbox')) {

                            targetLineGroup = sourceGroup.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            });
                            lineClass = 'out';

                            x1 = dummyLine.attr('x1');
                            x2 = dummyLine.attr('x2');
                            y1 = dummyLine.attr('y1');
                            y2 = dummyLine.attr('y2');
                        }

                        targetLineGroup
                                .append('line')
                                .attr('class', lineClass)
                                .attr('id', function () {
                                    return sourceCircleClass + '--' + sourceGroup.attr('id') + '__' + thisCircleClass + '--' + thisGroup.attr('id');
                                })
                                .attr('x1', dummyLine.attr('x1'))
                                .attr('real-x1', dummyLine.attr('x1'))
                                .attr('y1', dummyLine.attr('y1'))
                                .attr('real-y1', dummyLine.attr('y1'))
                                .attr('x2', dummyLine.attr('x2'))
                                .attr('real-x2', dummyLine.attr('x2'))
                                .attr('y2', dummyLine.attr('y2'))
                                .attr('real-y2', dummyLine.attr('y2'))
                                .attr('startGroup', dummyLine.attr('startGroup'))
                                .attr('endGroup', thisGroup.attr('id'))
                                .style('stroke', 'green')
                                .style('stroke-width', '3px')

                        ;
                        dummyLine.style('visibility', 'hidden');


                        console.log('DRAWING LINE ON : ', targetLineGroup.attr('id'))

                    })
            ;

    var svg = d3.select('svg').node();

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function () {
                        var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
                        return {x: t[0], y: t[1]};
                    }).on('dragstart', function () {
                        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    }).on('drag', function () {

                        var g = d3.select(this);

                        var mouse = {dx: d3.event.x, dy: d3.event.y};
                        var currentObj = {
                            x: g.select('image').attr('x'),
                            y: g.select('image').attr('y'),
                            width: g.select('image').attr('width'),
                            height: g.select('image').attr('height')
                        };
                        var parentObj = {
                            x: (Number(g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('x'))), // + Number(d3.transform(parent.attr('transform')).translate[0])),
                            y: (Number(g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('y'))), // + Number(d3.transform(parent.attr('transform')).translate[1])),
                            width: g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('width'),
                            height: g.select(function () {
                                return this.parentNode;
                            }).select('.container').attr('height')
                        };


                        var loc = getXY(mouse, currentObj, parentObj);
                        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + loc.x + ',' + loc.y + ')');
//                        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');

                        var thisGroupId = d3.select(this).attr('id');
                        var groupClass = d3.select(this).attr('class');

                        var thisGroupClass = d3.select(this).attr('class');
                        var tLineClass;
                        if (thisGroupClass == 'qbox') {
                            tLineClass = 'out'
                        } else {
                            tLineClass = 'in'
                        }

                        d3.selectAll('line.' + tLineClass)[0].forEach(function (e1) {

                            var line = d3.select(e1);

                            var lineId = line.attr('id');




                            var lineStartGroup = lineId.split('__')[0].split('--')[1];
                            var lineStartSide = lineId.split('__')[0].split('--')[0];
                            var lineEndGroup = lineId.split('__')[1].split('--')[1];
                            var lineEndSide = lineId.split('__')[1].split('--')[0];

                            console.log('-------------------');
                            console.log(lineId);
                            console.log(lineStartGroup);
                            console.log(lineEndGroup);
                            console.log('-------------------');

                            var c;
                            var ctm;

                            if (thisGroupId == lineStartGroup) {
                                var t = d3.transform(d3.select('#' + thisGroupId).attr('transform')).translate;

                                if (lineStartSide == 'left') {
                                    c = d3.select('#' + lineStartGroup).select('.left');
                                    ctm = c.node().getCTM();
                                } else {
                                    c = d3.select('#' + lineStartGroup).select('.right');
                                    ctm = c.node().getCTM();
                                }

                                var x = d3.transform(c.select(function () {
                                    return this.parentNode;
                                }).attr('transform')).translate;


                                console.log('START e'+ctm['e']);
                                console.log('START ex'+x[0]);
                                console.log('START f'+ctm['f']);
                                console.log('START fx'+x[0]);
                                line.attr('x1', Number(c.attr('cx')) + Number(x[0]));
                                line.attr('y1', Number(c.attr('cy')) + Number(x[1]));
                            }

                            if (thisGroupId == lineEndGroup) {
//                                var t = d3.transform(d3.select('#' + thisGroupId).attr('transform')).translate;
//
//                                line.attr('x2', Number(line.attr('real-x2')) + Number(t[0]));
//                                line.attr('y2', Number(line.attr('real-y2')) + Number(t[1]));

                                if (lineEndSide == 'left') {
                                    c = d3.select('#' + lineEndGroup).select('.left');

                                } else {
                                    c = d3.select('#' + lineEndGroup).select('.right');

                                }

                                var x = d3.transform(c.select(function () {
                                    return this.parentNode;
                                }).attr('transform')).translate;

                                ctm = c.node().getCTM();
                                console.log('END circleId'+c.attr('id'));

                                line.attr('x2', Number(c.attr('cx')) + Number(x[0]));
                                line.attr('y2', Number(c.attr('cy')) + Number(x[1]));

                            }


                        });


                    })

            ;

    opBox.call(drag);
    qBox.call(drag);
    circles.call(cDrag);

    var circleID;

    var dummyLine;

    circles.on('mouseover', function () {
        circleID = d3.select(this).attr('id');
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        circleID = null;
    })

function getXY(mouse, current, parent) {

    var obj = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    var dx = mouse.dx;
    var dy = mouse.dy;

    obj.x = dx;
    obj.y = dy;

    var xGap = current.x - parent.x;
    var yGap = current.y - parent.y;

    if (dx < 0) {
        if ((dx + xGap) < 0) {
            obj.x = -1 * xGap + 10;
        }
    } else {
        if ((dx + xGap) > parent.width) {
            obj.x = parent.width - xGap - current.width - 10;
        }
    }

    if (dy < 0) {
        if ((dy + yGap) < 0) {
            obj.y = -1 * yGap + 10;
        }

    } else {
        if ((dy + yGap) > parent.height) {
            obj.y = parent.height - yGap - current.height - 10;
        }
    }


    return obj;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience developing visual editors, I can say that relative positions (such as x,y in Operator) can and shoud be managed as data.

Try changing that data (and not directly the x,y attributes of the svg element), and binding the data in a d3js way. It will be much more idiomatic and fast.

PS: I know about separation of model and view, and I know about the bad side of storing visual properties along the model, but if it will be only a view for that model, it is for sure the best approach.